# Nodejs delete from table but select not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
user_id=3;
//Delete from table query working perfect
db.query("DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id=" + user_id, function(dberr,dbres){
    addUserInventories(detail, req, function(err,invres){                       
        getHomePageDataWithInvntory(req, function(request, response){
            callback(null, response);
        });
    });
});

//Here add record in table 
function addUserInventories(detail, req, callback){
//After insertion called following and working perfect
     return callback(null, null);
});


//Here retrieve record from table but not getting result after delete and insert operation
function getHomePageDataWithInvntory(req, callback){
    user_id=3;
    db.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=" + user_id, function(err, results){
          callback(null, results);  //Here result getting empty array
    });
 });
```

> In above code **Delete** record and **Insert** record work perfect but **Retrieving** record is not working.
>
> Note : There is no any syntax error in SQL Query and In log file it print `SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=3`

Comment: What are the logs ?

Comment: What you mean by logs @Alburkerk

Comment: what error do you get in the select query ? Also check if you have any record with the user_id you are doing the query?

Comment: @AmanGupta I print log also it display correct SQL Query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=3`

Answer (score 0):

When I got this kind of error, I always save them with the same process :

1. **console.log your query string** before using it
2. Use a **database client** like Sequel Pro, MySQL Workbench for sql
3. Copy paste your query manually in the client and run it
4. Generally, you'll get a syntax error, just solve it in the database client and your solution should work

Database client is not mandatory as you can run the query with command line, but the client will be a simpler interface for you and is more likely to give you more details on your syntax error.

Can you try this process ? If you don't succeed in solving the syntax error in the database client, you can put the query here so we can help you

***Just in case :*** with your example, I'll use this pattern to log the query if you have trouble to do it, this give you an idea of how to do it in your code

```
//Here retrieve record from table but not getting result after delete and insert operation
function getHomePageDataWithInvntory(req, callback){
  user_id=3;
  var queryString = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=" + user_id;
  console.log(queryString);

  db.query(queryString, function(err, results){
      callback(null, results);  //Here result getting empty array
  });
});
```

Comment: I print log also it display correct SQL Query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=3`

Comment: Can't you paste the real query log here ? And can you console.log the err and results variable from the callback ?

Comment: Then it seems you are requesting something that doesn't exist, can you run the **exact** same query in a mysql client and see if it is returning something different than no records ?

Comment: It working perfect in `Phpmyadmin` and return expected result

Comment: My flow is ok as per nodejs term and condition?

Comment: Yes there don't seems to have a nodejs problem, you would not get the callback if it was.. I am a bit out of idea, can you check you are not doing something like deleting the row, getting it, then adding it ? If you use this pattern, it will do this bug with the nodejs route, but as you add the row after, it will be present again for your Phpmyadmin query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150902/discussion-between-alburkerk-and-sadikhasan).